# Oracle export and import that will MERGE records?

Tags: oracle

I have a table X that exists in two databases. One DB is the source and the other is the target.

Is there a simple way to export table X and then run an import that will MERGE records into the table without overwriting (deleting) records?

For example:

Source table has records (first column is PK)

```
1 | ABC
2 | DEF
3 | GHI
```

Target table:

```
1 | DSF
3 | GHI
4 | TPZ
```

After running the process, I'm expecting this:

```
1 | ABC
2 | DEF
3 | GHI
4 | TPZ
```

I think one solution I read was to do an export and import into a staging table, then write a script that will merge the rows in the import database. I was wondering if there is any other option available in Oracle before I try this route out.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many rows you have, you could use Data Pump to export the contents of the target table, and then import that dump file into your source table. It would not be the most efficient method, but it may be the most straightforward if you're working with a small number of rows. The initial export would look something like:

```
expdp [USER]/[PASS]@[DATABASE] schemas=[SCHEMA] tables=[TARGET] directory=[DIRECTORY] dumpfile=[FILE].dmp logfile=[LOG].log
```

Using that same dump file, you would import it like so:

```
impdp [USER]/[PASS]@[DATABASE] schemas=[SCHEMA] tables=[TARGET] DIRECTORYtables=[TARGET] directory=[DIRECTORY] dumpfile=[FILE].dmp TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND logfile=[LOG].log
```

Using the APPEND flag should allow you to load all of the rows that are not already in the Source table.